# How do I prevent ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-amqp

What do I need to do to prevent the following Exception which is presumably thrown by RabbitMQ.

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:877)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:787)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:707)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:98)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:189)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1236)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:688)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1190)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1174)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1200(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:98)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'amqpLaunchSpringBatchJobFlow.channel#0'; nested exception is jp.ixam_drive.batch.service.JobExecutionRuntimeException: Failed to start job with name ads-insights-import and parameters {accessToken=<ACCESS_TOKEN>, id=act_1234567890, classifier=stats, report_run_id=1482330625184792, job_request_id=32}
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:449)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$400(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$1.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:784)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
    Caused by: jp.ixam_drive.batch.service.JobExecutionRuntimeException: Failed to start job with name ads-insights-import and parameters {accessToken=<ACCESS_TOKEN>, id=act_1234567890, classifier=stats, report_run_id=1482330625184792, job_request_id=32}
    at jp.ixam_drive.facebook.SpringBatchLauncher.launchJob(SpringBatchLauncher.java:42)
    at jp.ixam_drive.facebook.AmqpBatchLaunchIntegrationFlows.lambda$amqpLaunchSpringBatchJobFlow$1(AmqpBatchLaunchIntegrationFlows.java:71)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={accessToken=<ACCESS_TOKEN>, id=act_1234567890, classifier=stats, report_run_id=1482330625184792, job_request_id=32}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor193.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:125)
    at jp.ixam_drive.batch.service.JobOperationsService.launch(JobOperationsService.java:64)
    at jp.ixam_drive.facebook.SpringBatchLauncher.launchJob(SpringBatchLauncher.java:37)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

when I have 2 instances of Spring Boot application both of which run the following code in parallel to execute Spring Batch Jobs?

```
@Configuration
@Conditional(AmqpBatchLaunchCondition.class)
@Slf4j
public class AmqpAsyncAdsInsightsConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Value("${batch.launch.amqp.routing-keys.async-insights}")
    String routingKey;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow amqpOutboundAsyncAdsInsights(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("async_ads_insights")
                .<JobParameters, byte[]>transform(SerializationUtils::serialize)
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate).routingKey(routingKey)).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow amqpAdsInsightsAsyncJobRequestFlow(FacebookMarketingServiceProvider serviceProvider,
            JobParametersToApiParametersTransformer transformer, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, routingKey))
                .<byte[], JobParameters>transform(SerializationUtils::deserialize)
                .<JobParameters, ApiParameters>transform(transformer)
                .<ApiParameters>handle((payload, header) -> {
                    String accessToken = (String) header.get("accessToken");
                    String id = (String) header.get("object_id");
                    FacebookMarketingApi api = serviceProvider.getApi(accessToken);
                    String reportRunId = api.asyncRequestOperations().getReportRunId(id, payload.toMap());
                    ObjectNode objectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
                    objectNode.put("accessToken", accessToken);
                    objectNode.put("id", id);
                    objectNode.put("report_run_id", reportRunId);
                    objectNode.put("classifier", (String) header.get("classifier"));
                    objectNode.put("job_request_id", (Long) header.get("job_request_id"));
                    return serialize(objectNode);
                }).channel("ad_report_run_polling_channel").get();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private String serialize(JsonNode jsonNode) {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
    }
}

@Configuration
@Conditional(AmqpBatchLaunchCondition.class)
@Slf4j
public class AmqpBatchLaunchIntegrationFlows {

    @Autowired
    SpringBatchLauncher batchLauncher;

    @Value("${batch.launch.amqp.routing-keys.job-launch}")
    String routingKey;

    @Bean(name = "batch_launch_channel")
    public MessageChannel batchLaunchChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow amqpOutbound(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate,
            @Qualifier("batch_launch_channel") MessageChannel batchLaunchChannel) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(batchLaunchChannel)
                .<JobParameters, byte[]>transform(SerializationUtils::serialize)
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate).routingKey(routingKey)).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow amqpLaunchSpringBatchJobFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, routingKey))
                .handle(message -> {
                    String jobName = (String) message.getHeaders().get("job_name");
                    byte[] bytes = (byte[]) message.getPayload();
                    JobParameters jobParameters = SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
                    batchLauncher.launchJob(jobName, jobParameters);
                }).get();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class AsyncAdsInsightsConfiguration {

    @Value("${batch.core.pool.size}")
    public Integer batchCorePoolSize;

    @Value("${ixam_drive.facebook.api.ads-insights.async-poll-interval}")
    public String asyncPollInterval;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(name = "async_ads_insights")
    public MessageChannel adsInsightsAsyncJobRequestChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ad_report_run_polling_channel")
    public MessageChannel adReportRunPollingChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(batchCorePoolSize)).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow adReportRunPollingLoopFlow(FacebookMarketingServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(adReportRunPollingChannel())
                .<String>handle((payload, header) -> {
                    ObjectNode jsonNode = deserialize(payload);
                    String accessToken = jsonNode.get("accessToken").asText();
                    String reportRunId = jsonNode.get("report_run_id").asText();
                    try {
                        AdReportRun adReportRun = serviceProvider.getApi(accessToken)
                                .fetchObject(reportRunId, AdReportRun.class);
                        log.debug("ad_report_run: {}", adReportRun);
                        return jsonNode.set("ad_report_run", objectMapper.valueToTree(adReportRun));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("failed while polling for ad_report_run.id: {}", reportRunId);
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }).<JsonNode, Boolean>route(payload -> {
                    JsonNode adReportRun = payload.get("ad_report_run");
                    return adReportRun.get("async_percent_completion").asInt() == 100 &&
                            "Job Completed".equals(adReportRun.get("async_status").asText());
                }, rs -> rs.subFlowMapping(true,
                        f -> f.transform(JsonNode.class,
                                source -> {
                                    JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
                                    jobParametersBuilder
                                            .addString("accessToken", source.get("accessToken").asText());
                                    jobParametersBuilder.addString("id", source.get("id").asText());
                                    jobParametersBuilder
                                            .addString("classifier", source.get("classifier").asText());
                                    jobParametersBuilder
                                            .addLong("report_run_id", source.get("report_run_id").asLong());
                                    jobParametersBuilder
                                            .addLong("job_request_id", source.get("job_request_id").asLong());
                                    return jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters();
                                }).channel("batch_launch_channel"))
                        .subFlowMapping(false,
                                f -> f.transform(JsonNode.class, this::serialize)
                                        .<String>delay("delay", asyncPollInterval, c -> c.transactional()
                                                .messageStore(jdbcMessageStore()))
                                        .channel(adReportRunPollingChannel()))).get();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private String serialize(JsonNode jsonNode) {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private ObjectNode deserialize(String payload) {
        return objectMapper.readerFor(ObjectNode.class).readValue(payload);
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcMessageStore jdbcMessageStore() {
        JdbcMessageStore jdbcMessageStore = new JdbcMessageStore(dataSource);
        return jdbcMessageStore;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobParametersToApiParametersTransformer jobParametersToApiParametersTransformer() {
        return new JobParametersToApiParametersTransformer() {
            @Override
            protected ApiParameters transform(JobParameters jobParameters) {
                ApiParameters.ApiParametersBuilder builder = ApiParameters.builder();
                MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
                String level = jobParameters.getString("level");
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(level)) {
                    multiValueMap.set("level", level);
                }
                String fields = jobParameters.getString("fields");
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(fields)) {
                    multiValueMap.set("fields", fields);
                }
                String filter = jobParameters.getString("filter");
                if (filter != null) {
                    try {
                        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(filter);
                        if (jsonNode != null && jsonNode.isArray()) {
                            List<ApiFilteringParameters> filteringParametersList = new ArrayList<>();
                            List<ApiSingleValueFilteringParameters> singleValueFilteringParameters = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) jsonNode;
                            arrayNode.forEach(node -> {
                                String field = node.get("field").asText();
                                String operator = node.get("operator").asText();
                                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(field) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(operator)) {
                                    String values = node.get("values").asText();
                                    String[] valuesArray = !StringUtils.isEmpty(values) ? values.split(",") : null;
                                    if (valuesArray != null) {
                                        if (valuesArray.length > 1) {
                                            filteringParametersList.add(ApiFilteringParameters
                                                    .of(field, Operator.valueOf(operator), valuesArray));
                                        } else {
                                            singleValueFilteringParameters.add(ApiSingleValueFilteringParameters
                                                    .of(field, Operator.valueOf(operator), valuesArray[0]));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            if (!filteringParametersList.isEmpty()) {
                                builder.filterings(filteringParametersList);
                            }
                            if (!singleValueFilteringParameters.isEmpty()) {
                                builder.filterings(singleValueFilteringParameters);
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                    }
                }
                String start = jobParameters.getString("time_ranges.start");
                String end = jobParameters.getString("time_ranges.end");
                String since = jobParameters.getString("time_range.since");
                String until = jobParameters.getString("time_range.until");

                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(start) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(end)) {
                    builder.timeRanges(ApiParameters.timeRanges(start, end));
                } else if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(since) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(until)) {
                    builder.timeRange(new TimeRange(since, until));
                }
                String actionBreakdowns = jobParameters.getString("action_breakdowns");
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(actionBreakdowns)) {
                    multiValueMap.set("action_breakdowns", actionBreakdowns);
                }
                String attributionWindows = jobParameters.getString("action_attribution_windows");
                if (attributionWindows != null) {
                    try {
                        multiValueMap
                                .set("action_attribution_windows",
                                        objectMapper.writeValueAsString(attributionWindows.split(",")));
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                builder.multiValueMap(multiValueMap);
                String pageSize = jobParameters.getString("pageSize");
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(pageSize)) {
                    builder.limit(pageSize);
                }
                return builder.build();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here is how message flows:

```
   1. channel[async_ads_insights] ->IntegrationFlow[amqpOutboundAsyncAdsInsights]->[AMQP]->IntegrationFlow[amqpAdsInsightsAsyncJobRequestFlow]->channel[ad_report_run_polling_channel]->IntegrationFlow[adReportRunPollingLoopFlow]-IF END LOOP->channel[batch_launch_channel] ELSE -> channel[ad_report_run_polling_channel]

   2. channel[batch_launch_channel] -> IntegrationFlow[amqpOutbound]-> IntegrationFlow[amqpLaunchSpringBatchJobFlow]

   3. Spring Batch Job is launched.
```

The exception isn't thrown immediately after both instances are started, but after a while. Launching Spring Batch Jobs do succeeds but then start to fail with "A job instance already exists and is complete for..."

The job is for retrieving facebook ads results.

I would appreciate your insights into what is causing the error above.

I also have this configuration which does not use AMQP and works without any problem, but it is only for one instance.

```
@Configuration
@Conditional(SimpleBatchLaunchCondition.class)
@Slf4j
public class SimpleBatchLaunchIntegrationFlows {

    @Autowired
    SpringBatchLauncher batchLauncher;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(name = "batch_launch_channel")
    public MessageChannel batchLaunchChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.queue(jdbcChannelMessageStore(), "batch_launch_channel").get();
    }

    @Bean
    public ChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider channelMessageStoreQueryProvider() {
        return new MySqlChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcChannelMessageStore jdbcChannelMessageStore() {
        JdbcChannelMessageStore channelMessageStore = new JdbcChannelMessageStore(dataSource);
        channelMessageStore.setChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider(channelMessageStoreQueryProvider());
        channelMessageStore.setUsingIdCache(true);
        channelMessageStore.setPriorityEnabled(true);
        return channelMessageStore;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow launchSpringBatchJobFlow(@Qualifier("batch_launch_channel")
            MessageChannel batchLaunchChannel) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(batchLaunchChannel)
                .handle(message -> {
                    String jobName = (String) message.getHeaders().get("job_name");
                    JobParameters jobParameters = (JobParameters) message.getPayload();
                    batchLauncher.launchJob(jobName, jobParameters);
                }, e->e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(500).receiveTimeout(500))).get();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the different @Configuration that uses no AMQP(SimpleBatchLaunchIntegrationFlows) but then only for a single instance(no work is shared)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the Spring Batch documentation. When launching a new instance of a job, the job parameters must be unique.

A common solution is to add a dummy parameter with a UUID or similar but batch provides a strategy, e.g to increment a numeric parameter each time.

**EDIT**

There is a certain class of exceptions where the members of which are considered irrecoverable (fatal) and it makes no sense to attempt redelivery.

Examples include `MessageConversionException` - if we can't convert it the first time, we probably can't convert on a redelivery. The `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler` is the mechanism by which we detect such exceptions, and cause them to be permanently rejected (and not redelivered).

Other exceptions cause the message to be redelivered by default - there is another property `defaultRequeuRejected` which can be set to false to permanently reject all failures (not recommended).

You can customize the error handler by subclassing its `DefaultExceptionStrategy` - override `isUserCauseFatal(Throwable cause)` to scan the `cause` tree to look for a `JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException` and return true (`cause.getCause().getCause() instanceof ...`)

> I think it was triggered by the error thrown by the "SpringBatch job running already" exception.

That still indicates you have somehow received a second message with the same parameters; it's a different error because the original job is still running; that message is rejected (and requeued) but on subsequent deliveries you get the already completed exception.

So, I still say the root cause of your problem is duplicate requests, but you can avoid the behavior with a customized error handler in the channel adapter's listener container.

I suggest you log the duplicate message so you can figure out why you are getting them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know it’s not job parameters because each one of that are being executed do have a uniquely identifiable combination of job parameters. Jobs do execute for and do complete without error for a while, until this exception is thrown and it is when I start seeing in console that both instances are presumably picking up the same job identifiable parameters from AMQP, which don’t happen until the aforementioned exception is thrown. I thought that "Listener threw exception" is the case and I want to know how to prevent this.

Comment: It's unequivocal. If you get that exception you are trying to start a job with the same parameters. It has nothing to do with rabbitmq. Debug logs should help you track it down.

Comment: What I am seeing is ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler in the log
2017-10-07 10:26:24.572  WARN 55577 --- [erContainer#0-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

As per documentation it will "conditionally wraps the Exception in an AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException" and I am guessing this is causing the "re run
" of the same job with the same parameter.
What's AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException?

Comment: Never mind, i think it was triggered by the error thrown by the "SpringBatch job running already" exception. What I don't understand is job execution completes for like a couple of hundreds of jobs then it suddenly start throwing the exception mentioned above.

Comment: It appears that it is related to
 2017-10-07 11:51:27.571  WARN 59922 --- [erContainer#0-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

when this happens same message is refetched therefore Spring Batch Exception is thrown.

Comment: The "already running" exception still indicates a duplicate job request - see the edit to my answer for how to reject such messages.

Comment: Thanks four the thorough explanation. Your advice is extraordinarily helpful and always supportive.